Liquid Code in Standard Time instead of Military Time
I'm trying to edit our packing slip for Shopify so order.created_at no longer displays in military time and instead shows standard. Is there any way to code this?
I know html would allow something like this:
if (h = 13) {h = 1}
if (h = 14) {h = 2}
if (h = 15) {h = 3}
if (h = 16) {h = 4}
if (h = 17) {h = 5}
if (h = 18) {h = 6}
if (h = 19) {h = 7}
if (h = 20) {h = 8}
if (h = 21) {h = 9}
if (h = 22) {h = 10}
if (h = 23) {h = 11}
if (h = 24) {h = 12}

Is this plausible for it to return with am/pm instead of military?
I don't even know what to try.

You can convert the timestamp to whatever format you want using liquid filters
{{ order.created_at | date: "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %P}}. This will convert your order.created_at to the specific format you're asking. You can understand more about it here in the documentation
